# Mongodb example non working in their docs

Tags: mongodb

How do I run [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#pipeline-sequence-optimization) example? It completely not working. The syntax is wrong I think, at least when I paste it into my IDE, it's all red.